# Likelihood ratio tests and multiple testing

Tags: chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons, likelihood-ratio

I'm running various likelihood ratio tests, and assessing the significance of each as a chi-sq test, using the difference in number of parameters as the degrees of freedom.

There are quite a lot of these, plus some other tests as well. If I'm using LRTs like this, do I still need to account for multiple testing?

My intuition says no, because this is likelihood- rather than frequentist-based, which is partly the point of using LRTs in the first place. On the other hand I'm not sure if the chi-sq test does indeed mean it falls back on a frequentist test.

This seems a painfully elementary question, but one I haven't been able to find a straight answer for anywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you are doing many tests on the same hypothesis. Otherwise, it is a classical multiple testing problem...

By trying different models, you are increasing the type-I error rate, so that multiple testing adjustment is recommended. 
Then again, and sadly, very few researchers actually do this. 
If the models are similar, it may not be too bad since the test statistics would be strongly correlated. 
If the models differ, then the type-I error can be gravely inflated and you should definitely account for multiplicity.

Comment: I'm fitting a GLM to data, and removing variables one at a time, so I have a series of models M1 to M10. The comparisons are then M1/M2, M2/M3, ... up to M6/M7. After that there are the comparisons with the same hypothesis, namely M8/M7, M9/M7 and M10/M7.

If I understand you correctly then, only these last three test the same hypothesis?

Comment: It sounds like you are doing model selection. This is clearly related to multiple testing, but you should really start with some introductory text.